# Google's 'gsutil cp' command runs a checksum on the file transferred. Does Google's java storage API do the same?

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

From the [documentation on gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#checksum-validation):

"At the end of every upload or download the gsutil cp command validates that the checksum it computes for the source file/object matches the checksum the service computes. If the checksums do not match, gsutil will delete the corrupted object and print a warning message."

And here's some [sample code](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-java-samples) using their java storage API:

```
public static void uploadFile(String name, String contentType, File file, String bucketName)
    throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    InputStreamContent contentStream = new InputStreamContent(
            contentType, new FileInputStream(file));
    // Setting the length improves upload performance
    contentStream.setLength(file.length());
    StorageObject objectMetadata = new StorageObject()
        // Set the destination object name
        .setName(name)
        // Set the access control list to publicly read-only
        .setAcl(Arrays.asList(
            new ObjectAccessControl().setEntity("allUsers").setRole("READER")));

    // Do the insert
    Storage client = StorageFactory.getService();
    Storage.Objects.Insert insertRequest = client.objects().insert(
            bucketName, objectMetadata, contentStream);

    insertRequest.execute();
}
```

Is a checksum necessary to perform? Should I do it manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We recommend computing checksums on all uploads and downloads, and validating that the checksum you computed matches the one the service has. Doing this protects you against client or client library bugs that could corrupt the data on it's way to/from the cloud.

I'm going to open a bug to update that sample code, to include computing the checksum.